# Отправка сообщения через websocket golang

Tags: golang, websocket

Всем привет!
Только учусь программировать, не судите строго=)
Впервые столкнулся с вебсокетами, ни разу не настраивал
Задача простая: произвести соединение и отправить сообщение пользователю

Начитавшись на просторах интернета, получается что то вот такое

Подключение

```
func echo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    con, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("upgrade:", err)
        return
    }
    defer con.Close()
    for {
        mt, message, err := con.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("read:", err)
            break
        }
        log.Printf("recv: %s", message)
        err = con.WriteMessage(mt, message)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("write:", err)
            break
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    log.SetFlags(0)
    http.HandleFunc("/echo", echo)
}
```

Отправка сообщения из метода

```
jsonData, _ := json.Marshal(data)
users := make(map[string]*websocket.Conn)
_ = users[uid].WriteJSON(jsonData)
```

Как вы понимаете, это не работает и я в каком то ступоре.
Подскажите пожалуйста, я вообще в правильном направлении действую?
Уверен что кто то уже делал такую самую простую настройку, отзовитесь пожалуйста)

Comment: а что конкретно не работает? вы web-сервер не запустили

Answer (score 0):

Это пример из Gorilla WebSocket, echo сервер.

https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/echo

Браузер получает от сервера веб страницу со скриптом, скрипт устанавливает с сервером вебсокетное соединение, отправляет серверу сообщение и тут же получает его обратно.
Чтобы выполнить пример нужно произвести несколько простых действий:

1. Перенести к себе файл `websocket/examples/echo/server.go`. Этого достаточно.
2. Запустить сервер `$ go run server.go`
3. Открыть в браузере страничку сервера (http://127.0.0.1:8080), нажать кнопку OPEN. В этот момент браузер запросит соединение с сервером, соединение установится и вы это увидите. Обратите внимание что запрос, происходит не из кода на Go, а из скрипта JavaScript (78 строка сервера), т.е. из самого браузера `ws = new WebSocket("{{.}}");`.
   Принимается же запрос в 23 строке сервера именно в гошном приложении `c, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)`.

Далее, после установки соединения, обе стороны запускают соответствующую случаю логику отправки, обработки и получения сообщений.

4. Отправить кнопкой Send серверу свое сообщение (Hello world!).